# error: reached the recursion limit while auto-dereferencing T

Tags: rust

I wonder if this is normal or it is a bug :

```
struct A<T> (T);

impl<T> Add<A<T>, A<T>> for A<T> 
where T: Add<T, T> + Deref<T> + Copy {
    fn add(&self, &A(b): &A<T>) -> A<T> {
        let A(a) = *self;
        A(a.add(&b))
    }
}
```

produces this error:

```
<anon>:7:11: 7:12 error: reached the recursion limit while auto-dereferencing T [E0055]
<anon>:7         A(a.add(&b))
```

while replacing `a.add(&b)` by `a+b` compiles without error

[playpen](http://is.gd/W84fwz)

isn't `a+b`supposed to be just sugar for `a.add(&b)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short version:** `T` implementing `Deref<T>` makes no sense and so the differences in how method calls and operator calls work with regards to dereferencing the left hand side blows things up, because `a + b` is *not* quite the same as `a.add(&b)`.

**Long version:**

The `+` operator and [`Add.add`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html#tymethod.add) operate differently as far as taking of references is concerned.

**The `+` operator** takes both operands by reference itself. `a + b` for operands of respective types `A` and `B` requires that there be an implementation of `Add<B, C>` for `A` and will produce a value of type `C`. As stated, `a` and `b` are taken by reference; it makes these references itself, silently; there is no guessing. Here’s how they work:

```
let a = 1i;
let b = a + a;    // this one works
let c = a + &a;   // mismatched types: expected `int`, found `&int` (expected int, found &-ptr)
let d = &a + a;   // binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `&int`
let e = &a + &a;  // binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `&int`
```

No dereferencing occurs in any of this, and so the dodgy `T: Deref<T>` requirement doesn’t blow anything up.

**`Add.add`** takes both values by reference. As a regular function call, it has the ability to automatically dereference and reference the left hand side when necessary. While the right hand side, as a method argument, is passed in as it is, the left hand side is dereferenced as much as possible to find all the possible methods that could be being meant by `add`. Normally this is fine and it would do what you want, but in this case it won’t, because `T` (of which type `a` is) implements `Deref<T>`. So dereferencing gets it a `T`. And then `T`, implementing `Deref<T>`, dereferences to `T`. What’s more, `T` implements `Deref<T>` and so dereferences to `T`. It keeps doing this until it reaches the recursion limit. Really, `T` implementing `Deref<T>` just makes no sense at all.

For comparison, here are some demonstrations of how the method-call add works:

```
let a = 1i;
let b = a.add(a);      // mismatched types: expected `&int`, found `int` (expected &-ptr, found int)
let c = a.add(&a);     // this one works (a reference to the LHS is taken automatically)
let d = (&a).add(a);   // mismatched types: expected `&int`, found `int` (expected &-ptr, found int)
let e = (&a).add(&a);  // this one works (LHS is dereferenced and then rereferenced)
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanations ! I added the deref trait thinking it just means that  T can be dereferenced (to correct an other error in my code), which is not what it realy means. But it was worth the explanetions about the difference between `a+b` and `a.add(&b)`